# Mobile Offline Dynamics CRM app error

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, offline, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics365-app-mobile

Mobile offline profile defines that every account should be downloaded. Status of the accounts is "available" in the mobile app. However, when we go offline, no account record can be opened due to following error in Event Viewer:

> The requested record was not found or you do not have sufficient permissions to view it.
>   Inner Error Message:
>   **
>
> Offline store failed with error: 'Error: SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: account
>       at Microsoft.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMforWindows10!+0x2c1548
>       at Microsoft.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMforWindows10!+0x366779
>       at Microsoft.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMforWindows10!+0x36552a
>       at System.Collections.Generic.List..ctor(Collections.Generic.IEnumerable collection)
>       at Microsoft.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMforWindows10!+0x35bda2
>       at Microsoft.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMforWindows10!+0x35bb44
>       at System.Action.Invoke()
>       at Microsoft.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMforWindows10!+0x35b50c
>       at Microsoft.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMforWindows10!+0x35b3af' while trying to retrieve with key 'account:'
>
> **

Also, following status is maintained in the application:

> "An administrator made changes to the Dynamics 365 system that might affect offline availability. We're working on getting everything back in sync."

This message is more than 1 week for now.

Anybody has an idea to fix this? Version is V8.2 and user has sufficient permissions to access accounts.